Gradle stops build at the compileJava stage without an error
I don't know how to describe my problem. I just create a new project via spring initializr or spring boot project in Intellij idea, and when I try to run Main, the build just stops at compileJava stage
Before this I wrote in another project where at least tests were run, but here I have no idea at all
Gradle: 
My build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}
group = 'org.remsoftware'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


I don't even know where to dig, any help would be welcome
Checked Project structure, following the example of the working project, does not help.
Checked Build tools settings, does not help.
Changed build.gradle as on the working project, the situation did not change.
Deleting the directory .gradle did not help, maven works fine
I just saw that an error log is created when the project is started, but I still don't understand anything. Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/kBN87PRi

Please copy or type the text of the error into the question. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

I literally wrote in the title that the build is canceled WITHOUT error. No stack trace is displayed. If you need some special error, please write more details on how I can get it

Paste the text from that pane instead of using an image. And add the steps you are doing to execute.

A SIGSEGV occurred in libnative-platform-file-events.dylib (native code) that caused the JVM to crash. Which OS are you using? Which version of Gradle?

@Slaw Was using gradle 8.8, the os is macOs 11.7.10 Big Sur(old os). When I switched to gradle 8.7 everything worked. Thanks! You can post a reply and I'll flag it. But it's weird that no error was displayed, I had the error panel empty.
